# Wordpress load a stylesheet through plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written a WordPress plugin and want to make it include some css stylesheets,  I have tried to use the process I usually use in a themes functions.php file...

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_script','register_my_scripts');

function register_my_scripts(){
    $dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
    wp_enqueue_style( $dir . 'css/style1.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( $dir . 'css/style2.css');
}
```

But this is not loading anything,  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `wp_enqueue_style('custom-style', plugins_url( '/css/my-style.css', __FILE__ ), array(),'all');` where `plugins_url` is relative to plugin base without slash.

Comment: i see your action hook 'wp_enqueue_script' missing 's' character. It is hook action, not function so right must is 'wp_equeue_scripts' [1].

[1]. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The hook you need to use is wp_enqueue_scripts, you were missing the 's'.

You're getting the directory path when what you need is the directory URL.

wp_enqueue_style's first parameter is a handle and not the URL.

```
function wpse_load_plugin_css() {
    $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'style1', $plugin_url . 'css/style1.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style2', $plugin_url . 'css/style2.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_load_plugin_css' );
```

Answer (score 9):

You are using [plugin_dir_path](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path) which outputs filesystem directory path. Instead you need URL.

Also the first parameter of [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) is `$handler` name.

Use [plugins_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url)

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style1', plugins_url( 'css/style1.css' , __FILE__ ) );
```

**Full code:**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','register_my_scripts');

function register_my_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style1', plugins_url( 'css/style1.css' , __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style2', plugins_url( 'css/style2.css' , __FILE__ ) );
}
```

Comment: it's wp_enqueue_style( 'style2', plugins_url( 'css/style2.css' , dirname(\_\_FILE__) ) );  see : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url#Common_Usage

Comment: @luciole135 If you are using the `plugins_url()` function in a file that is nested inside a subdirectory of your plugin directory, you should use `dirname(__FILE__)` can be used if file isn't in the root of plugin directory.

Comment: Yes, now i use plugin_dir_url()

Comment: this code is for scripts, not for style.

Comment: @DebbieKurth You can use `wp_enqueue_script` for injecting scripts.

Answer (score 2):

try :

`wp_enqueue_style('custom-style', plugins_url( '/css/my-style.css', __FILE__ ), array(),'all');` where `plugins_url` is relative to plugin base without slash.

Answer (score 0):

Load styles from wp plugin folder using plugin url

```
function add_plugin_stylesheet() 
    {
      wp_enqueue_style( 'style1', plugins_url( '/css/styleFileName1.css', __FILE__ ) );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'style2', plugins_url( '/css/styleFileName2.css', __FILE__ ) );
    }

    add_action('admin_print_styles', 'add_plugin_stylesheet');
```